# In Typescript, My exported Javascript type is neither a function or a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I'm new to Typescript and Javascript I got to admit. I have a repo now initialized with NextJS and I am trying to import a third party *.js to my project as a `component` in such way I could import it from my other typescript files.

The one I used is [MSABrowser](https://github.com/thekaplanlab/msabrowser/blob/master/javascript/msabrowser.js).

What I have tried:

I have made small personal changes on that script so probably I cannot import as a released package. Anyway, I put this `msabrowser.js` file under `components/msabrowser/` and import it using ES6 grammar like

```
import { MSABrowser, MSAProcessor } from "@/components/msabroswer/msabrowser"
```

And also, I made a `msabrowser.d.ts` file under the same folder, writter like this to export both `MSABroswer` and `MSAProcessor`

```
interface MSAProcessor {
  (options: { fasta: string; hasConsensus?: boolean }): MSAProcessor;

  sequenceDetails: any[];
  processedSequences: string[];
  fasta: string;
}
declare const MSAProcessor: MSAProcessor;
export = MSAProcessor;

export class MSABrowser {
  constructor(options: {
    id: string;
    msa: MSAProcessor;
    annotations?: any[];
    alterations?: any[];
  });
}
```

I use the following code to import and use MSABrowser and MSAProcessor:

```
viewer = new MSABrowser({
  id: "myMSABrowser",
  msa: new MSAProcessor({
    fasta: content,
    hasConsensus: false,
  }),
  annotations: annotations,
  alterations: alterations,
});
```

However my Chrome keeps complaining me:
`_components_msabrowser_msabrowser__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.MSAProcessor is not a constructor`. Well If I remove `new` keyword to treat it as a function. It would say: `TypeError: (0 , _components_msabrowser_msabrowser__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.MSAProcessor) is not a function`

Doesn't know if this help, but in my `tsconfig`, my `target` and `module` are all set to `esnext`

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `export = MSAProcessor;`, that's pretty deprecated

Comment: Please show us the actual JS `export` declarations, which are causing you trouble, not just the type declarations (that may or may not be accurate).

Comment: "*I remove new keyword to treat it as a function*" - the error message does not say that you should treat it as a function (and after all, you *want* to construct an instance of the class!), it says that the export could not be found (and is probably `undefined`)

Comment: @Bergi Hi thanks for the reply. The code I use is almost the same with js code here: https://github.com/thekaplanlab/msabrowser/blob/master/javascript/msabrowser.js

Comment: @Bergi following this documentation here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-function-d-ts.html That is pretty strange to me where they even don't differentiate `Greeter` and `greeter`

Comment: specificly, I delete `colorSchema` in MSABrowser definition in my version, but I think it won't bother in this case.

Comment: Uh, there is not `export` declaration in that entire file? It looks like it was meant to be executed as a script and define global variables. If you're editing it anyway, you should add some `export`s

Comment: @Bergi probably I misunderstand the relationship between my `msabrowser.d.ts` and `msabrowser.js`? I thought my declaration (also export) code in .d.ts file help me export function/class in my .js file.

Comment: No. The JS code needs to run and function alone. The declarations file only helps the TypeScript compiler to typecheck the code.